# Java - CoreNLP Turning String into Tree

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have recently begun using coreNLP and was wondering how I might construct a tree from a string. For example given the String `"My dog also likes eating sausage"`, how do I output the following:

`"(ROOT  (S (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog)) (ADVP (RB also)) (VP (VBZ likes) (S (VP (VBG eating) (NP (NN sausage))))) (. .)))"`

I have scoured the internet and the coreNLP documentation but I just can't seem to find any tutorials or examples. I would really appreciate your help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer:

```
System.out.println(new edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Sentence("My dog also likes eating sausage").parse())
```

In general, if you want more control than the simple API offers, you want to construct a pipeline with the `parse` annotator, and then get the TreeAnnotation attached to the sentence you want to print.

Comment: How might I construct a pipeline with the parse annotator and get the TreeAnnotation attached? Thanks.